# conformal mapping $\mathbb{C}^{*} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \backslash \{p\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

The task was whether $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ can be conformally mapped to  $\mathbb{C} \backslash \pm 1$

Then I read that: [https://matmor.unam.mx/~robert/cur/2010-1%20CA/CA6.pdf](https://matmor.unam.mx/%7Erobert/cur/2010-1%20CA/CA6.pdf)

> $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C} \backslash$ {p} for any p ∈ $\mathbb{C}$, but not to
> any other subset of $\mathbb{C}$

I may not understand this correctly, but does it mean that $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ can be only mapped to $\mathbb{C} \backslash$ $\{p\}$, when $p$ is a single value? so I can not exclude 2 values (as in $\pm 1$) at the same time?

---

My questions:
How can I show that:

> $\mathbb{C}^{*}$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{C} \backslash$ {p} for any p ∈ $\mathbb{C}$, but not to
> any other subset of $\mathbb{C}$

and how would the maps look like?

Comment: Show that any holomorphic map from $\mathbb C^*$ cannot have a bounded image unless constant (Liouville and Riemann singularity removal); but any open plane subset $U$ that misses at least two points has a (nonconstant) holomorphic map into the unit disc, so any non constant holomorphic map from $\mathbb C^*$ must have image either the full plane of the plane minus a point, so in particular $\mathbb C^*$ cannot be conformal to anything else and it's obviously not conformal with the full plane; topologically, of course, $\mathbb C^*$ is homeomorphic with any punctured disc

Comment: @Conrad: The same reasoning shows that there is no nonconstant bounded holomorphic map on the complement of any finite subset of $\mathbb{C}$.  I don't think there's a way to prove this without using something stronger like Little Picard.

Comment: @Conrad: Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $z\mapsto z+p$ does the job for $\mathbb C^*$ to $\mathbb C/\{p\}$.

The topology of $\mathbb C^*$ and $\mathbb C/\{\pm \}$ are different. They are not even homeomorphic to each other, and definitely not holomorphic.

To show $\mathbb C^*$ is not conformally equivalent to any other subset of $\mathbb C$. Say $f:C^*\xrightarrow{\sim} X\subset\mathbb C$, since $\mathbb C^*$ is not homeomorphic to $\mathbb C$, $X$ misses at least one point of $\mathbb C$. By shifting, without loss of generality, we may assume $X$ misses $0$ as well.

Suppose $f$ is a biholomorphic map from $\mathbb C^*$ to its image. Then since $f$ is injective, by Great Picard, $0$ can only be either removable or a pole. If $0$ is removable, then $f$ is entire, and thus by Picard's little, the analytic extension of $f$ can miss at most one point, and hence $f(\mathbb C^*)$ can miss at most two, but we have already shown it cannot miss two, due to topology. If $0$ is a pole, then we have $g(z):=\frac{1}{f(1/z)}$ is a biholomorphic map from $\mathbb C^*$ to $X'$ where $X'$ is the image of $X$ under the bihomolorphic map $z\mapsto 1/z$ on $\mathbb C^*$ that contains $X$. Since $0$ is removable for $g$, we conclude as above $g(\mathbb C^*)$ misses only one point, and hence $f(\mathbb C^*)$ only misses one point as well.

If we more carefully track the details in the above argument, it can be shown that the biholomorphic group of $\mathbb C^*$ is generated by $z\mapsto az, z\mapsto 1/z$ for nonzero $a$, hence the group is isomorphic to $\mathbb C^*\rtimes (\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$

Comment: Little Picard is enough if you just precompose with $\exp$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. There must be lots of improvements and even much simpler ways to do it, such as the way @Conrad proposed.

Comment: Thank you very much.